# How can I solve "npm run production" error?

Tags: laravel, npm, production

My app runs good in local computer. But cannot get it started on remote VPS
(ubuntu18.04).THis is my first vps, I am a noob..

Can anyone see what silly error I am making?

When I run npm run production  I get the error:

```
root@cluego:/var/www/laravel/node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin# npm run production
npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-22-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "production"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2

npm ERR! missing script: production
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/www/laravel/node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/npm-debug.log
root@cluego:/var/www/laravel/node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin#
```

The npm-debug.log says:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'run', 'production' ]
2 info using npm@3.5.2
3 info using node@v8.10.0
4 verbose stack Error: missing script: production
4 verbose stack     at run (/usr/share/npm/lib/run-script.js:147:19)
4 verbose stack     at /usr/share/npm/lib/run-script.js:57:5
4 verbose stack     at /usr/share/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:345:5
4 verbose stack     at handleExists (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:318:20)
4 verbose stack     at FSReqWrap.cb [as oncomplete] (fs.js:312:19)
5 verbose cwd /var/www/laravel/node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin
6 error Linux 4.15.0-22-generic
7 error argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "production"
8 error node v8.10.0
9 error npm  v3.5.2
10 error missing script: production
11 error If you need help, you may report this error at:
11 error     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
12 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch-poll": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --watch-poll --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "hot": "node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "production": "node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.0-beta3",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "cross-env": "^3.2.4",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "laravel-mix": "^6.0.13",
    "lodash": "^4.16.2",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "sass": "^1.15.2",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.1",
    "vue": "^2.4.4",
    "vue-resource": "^1.3.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.5.0",
    "croppie": "^2.6.5",
    "dotenv": "^5.0.1",
    "summernote": "^0.8.10"
  }
}
```

I am sure I am missing something trivial. But I cannot figure out what it is.

When I try  `nmp install`, I get errors as well:

```
/var/www/laravel# npm install
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@1.7.0: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated babel-preset-es2015@6.24.1:   Thanks for using Babel: we recommend using babel-preset-env now: please read https://babeljs.io/env to update!
npm WARN deprecated extract-text-webpack-plugin@2.1.2: Deprecated. Please use https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
loadDep:fsevents -> reque | |####################################################-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-22-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code EMISSINGARG

npm ERR! typeerror Error: Missing required argument #1
npm ERR! typeerror     at andLogAndFinish (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:31:3)
npm ERR! typeerror     at fetchPackageMetadata (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:51:22)
npm ERR! typeerror     at resolveWithNewModule (/usr/share/npm/lib/install/deps.js:456:12)
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:7
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/node_modules/iferr/index.js:13:50
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:37:12
npm ERR! typeerror     at addRequestedAndFinish (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:82:5)
npm ERR! typeerror     at returnAndAddMetadata (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:117:7)
npm ERR! typeerror     at pickVersionFromRegistryDocument (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:134:20)
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:109:7
npm ERR! typeerror This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR! typeerror     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/www/laravel/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: I had not seen the edit to the question. If you can't install the dependencies it could bethe node / npm version as mentioned [here](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/588).

Comment: THe links suggests upgrading webpack cli, which is not in my package.json at all. Webpack.mix.js is supposed to be installed with Laravel.

I notice now that a lot of dependencies are in the DevDepency in my package.json. Like jquery and cross-env. Shouldn't these be in "dependencies"?

I did what was suggested in the link:
# npm install -g n
# n stable

It did not help.

Comment: The links suggests upgrading webpack cli, which is not in my package.json at all. I have laravel.mix.


I did what was suggested in the link:
# npm install -g n
# n stable

It did not help.

Comment: I mean upgrade node, not webpack cli. Try removing cache first: `npm cache clean -f` then  `npm install -g n`  and `n stable`. Then you may need to restart your terminal to see the updated node version `node -v` (it should be 14). After that try `npm install` again.

Comment: I am pretty sure your problem is node version 8... upgrade it to at least 12